# Dynamic creation of forms.ImageField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Sorry for my English.

I have a problem with the **forms.ImageField**. The problem is, that I want to set initial value to this field dynamically and widget **ClearableFileInput** will display the "*Current link*" and *checkbox*. I read somewhere, that I have to pass **dictionary File** with  attribute **url**, and then, widget knows to display it. But I don't know how pass it properly...

```
if attr.type == "Img":
    self.fields [title] = forms.ImageField (required = bool(required))

    # Where here, I have to assign an initial value.
    # Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign value to ImageField while rendering the form such as

```
initialValues={
'textField1':'value for text field 1',
'textField2':'value for text field 2',
'imageField': someModel.objects.get(id=someId).logo
}

form = myForm(initial=initialValues)
```

Comment: i overrided __init__ of myForm , i need assign value inside of __init__

Comment: Then you need to create an `__init__` method inside your form class and assign anything you want.

Comment: i yet overrided init, but when  i  assign file object to ImageField ,nothing happen

Comment: it's work , i just need to assign to initial value , object of type `ImageFieldFile`

Answer (score 0):

it's work , i just need to assign to initial value , object of type ImageFieldFile

```
self.fields[title].initial = ImageFieldFile (file)
```